# If N is a quadratic residue modulo p for all primes p<N, is N a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, quadratic-residues

It is known that $N$ is a perfect square if and only if $N$ is a quadratic residue for every prime $p$.  This gives a good probabilistic algorithm for testing if a randomly chosen positive integer is a perfect square - simply compute it's Legendre Symbol for a sufficiently large set of randomly chosen primes.  A single result of $-1$ definitively tells you that $N$ is not a perfect square, while repeated results of only $+1$ or $0$ increase the probability that $N$ is a perfect square.

This probabilistic test could be much quicker with lower probability of a false positive if we could check only primes less than the integer $N$.  The proofs I've seen that $N$ is a perfect square IFF $N$ is a QR mod p for **all** primes $p$ cannot be used to prove the result using only the finitely many primes less than $N$.

Has anyone seen or know of a proof of this more specific result, or alternatively, know of a counter-example?  I've burned more than a few CPU cycles on Mathematica looking for a counterexample and have not found one yet.

Comment: Heuristically, if $n$ is not a perfect square, then for a "random" prime $p$, with $\text{gcd}(n,p)=1$, one would expect $n$ to be a quadratic residue with probability $1/2$. Thus, it gets harder and harder to find counterexamples, as $n$ gets larger and larger. So save the CPU cycles! You might need them for something that has a better chance of success.

Comment: Back of an envelope calculation suggests that modulo $210=2\times 3 \times 5 \times 7$ has small "non-square" "residues" like $225\equiv 15$ (but $15$ is not a square mod $13$). (allowing $0$ as a residue for the moment) I wonder if the small counter examples $2, 3, 6$ are the only ones (no time to investigate further).

Comment: This is not a duplicate, since it is asking about $p < n$, not $p > n$.

Comment: Is there such a solution given that $n>2$ is prime? This makes the square $0$ invalid, as no primes divide $n$ except $n$ itself now.

Answer (score 5):

No. For example, $\;6\;$ is a quadratic residue mod $\;2,3\;\text{ and }\,5\;$ .

Comment: This where Homer Simpson hits his head and say "Do-oh".  I was foolishly testing numbers greater than 10.  And probably my Mathematica programming skills are still rusty.  Thanks Don.

Comment: Even smaller example: $2$ is a quadratic residue mod each member of the empty set.

Answer (score -3):

A related problem: It is true that if $n$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ for *all* primes $p$ then $n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: The OP already mentioned this fact.